# How can i get the files that are not having .txt extension in java

Tags: java, file

Can anybody tell me how can i get all files from a directory that are not having .txt extension. I have written for .txt extension but not getting how to modify it for getting the files that doesn't have .txt extension. 
here is my code

```
import java.io.*;

public class OnlyExt implements FilenameFilter {
String ext;

public OnlyExt(String ext) {
    this.ext = "." + ext;
}

public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.endsWith(ext);


}
```

}

and here ext="txt"

pls help me. thanks .

Comment: What is the opposite of  true?

Comment: but how can i get list of those files???

Comment: Wow!  You're trying to code GUIs when you are unaware of the conditional 'not'?  Get ye' [back to the basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)!

Comment: we have solved our problem. Thanks for ans by @Pangea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the **!** ([unary negation operator](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-logical.html))

```
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) 
{
    return !name.endsWith(ext);
}
```